# Active X Error With Excel 2016 And Late Binding

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, office365

I have `Microsoft Office 365 Business` installed on my PC and am attempting to run `Access VBA` to create an Excel Object.  This is my Access VBA syntax I am  using

```
Dim xl As Object, wb As Object, ws As Object, ch As Object

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

However, it hits the `CreateObject` line and throws the image below, but **ONLY** on my PC running Office 365 Business.  If I run this same syntax on a computer running Office 2010 it executes exactly as it should and creates the Excel Object error free.

What must I change in order to be able to run this syntax with `Microsoft Office 365 Business`?

[image: Error Message]

**EDIT**
This is the only Registry Key that I see - it is close, but not exactly what was stated in the comments.
[image: Registry Key]

Comment: To make ActiveX run with `Excel.Application` the following registry entry is needed: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.Application`. This points to a `CLSID`. Can you check wheter this exists? For me using `Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus` it does and so `CreateObject("Excel.Application")`works. If it not exists for you, a Office reinstall may help. But maybe it is simply not provided with `Microsoft Office 365 Business`? I have not found detailed informations about this. Maybe ask `Microsoft`?

Comment: @AxelRichter - see my edit, I have a key similar but not exactly.  Please advise.

Comment: Try `CreateObject("Excel.Application.16")`.

Comment: @AxelRichter - using "Excel.Application.16" has it working now, but not ideal.  I was using late binding in order to have the syntax execute on computers that were running from 2007 - 2016.  I have a feeling if I add in .16 that will limit it to a computer that runs Office 2016...

Comment: You are true, the 16 is pointing to the current version. So the general registry entry  `Excel.Application` is missing for you. You could insert it manually and let point it to the same `CLSID`. But I dont know **why** it is missing. Have you tried reinstall Office?

Comment: @AxelRichter - i have not tried that yet.  I will try to add the Excel.Application key and let it point to the CLSID so this will work across multiple versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to check to see if the CLSID exists before trying to call `CreateObject`.  You can use the ole32.dll function `CLSIDFromString` to test it (this is also used by VBA internally for `CreateObject` and `GetObject` calls):

```
'Note, this is the 32bit call - use PtrSafe for 64bit Office.
Private Declare Function CLSIDFromString Lib "ole32.dll" _
    (ByVal lpsz As LongPtr, ByRef pclsid As LongPtr) As Long
```

You can wrap it in a simple "exists" test something like this:

```
Private Function ClassIdExists(clsid As String) As Boolean
    Dim ptr As LongPtr
    Dim ret As Long
    ret = CLSIDFromString(StrPtr(clsid), ptr)
    If ret = 0 Then ClassIdExists = True
End Function
```

This lets you test for classes *before* you try to create them (and avoids using the error handler to catch bad CLSIDs):

```
Dim xl As Object
If ClassIdExists("Excel.Application") Then
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ElseIf ClassIdExists("Excel.Application.16") Then
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application.16")
Else
    MsgBox "Can't locate Excel class."
End If
```

Comment: This answers not the question **why** the general registry entry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.Application` does not exist. Normally **both** registry entries should exist if the Office version supports `COM` automation. `Excel.Application` is general and `Excel.Application.16` (`Excel.Application.[nn]`) points to the current Office version. So although your answer works, I don't think that doing this will be good practice in general since you would have to check all possible version numbers.