# Runtime error 429 activex component can't create object excel in excel 2016 on windows 10

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

Can someone check what's happening in my VBA app. 
It always return an error even if I already put a reference in the excel and office. (see attached images)

OS: Windows10

MS Office: Excel version 2016

PL: VBA

Thank you in advance!

[Code that has an error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9r98.png)

[References Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZIxC.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41405937/active-x-error-with-excel-2016-and-late-binding

Comment: Thank you Siddharth! I will try the ideas in the link you provided and will give you a feedback once done. God Bless sir! =)