# createObject("Excel.Application.11") not working

Tags: excel, vba

Set XlApp= createObject("Excel.Application.11","Localhost") doesnot work in For office 2016. Please let me know what should be the last no. for office 16.

regards
anna

Comment: `CreateObject ("Excel.Application")`

Comment: Thank you Davis!! ....it worked

Comment: Hi Davis, CreateObject("Outlook.applicatio.14") does not work with office 16.  Can you provide soln for this as well. Thank you

Comment: `CreateObject ("Outlook.Application")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't test it, but this should work for Office 2016:
`Set XlApp = createObject("Excel.Application.16","Localhost")`.

See also [Active X Error With Excel 2016 And Late Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41405937/active-x-error-with-excel-2016-and-late-binding)